# What's the point of Keras its Unstateful LSTM model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, batch-processing, stateful

Keras distinguishes "Stateful" and "Unstateful" LSTM's, by default having them configured as "Unstateful". This is something that confused me a lot as LSTM's by definition are stateful. Isn't the whole point of LSTM's that it retains and upates learnings from historic data sequentially using its cell states?

When digging deeper into the Keras documentation on "Stateful" option in their LSTM layers, it brings more questions to my mind:

1. If I understand correctly, an "Unstateful" LSTM in Keras is basically clearing the cell states after each batch it trains on. It seems that this destroys the whole purpose of LSTM's, or at least reduces its usefulness to the size of a batch.

In line with what I mentioned, I'm confused why this is the case? ( Is this just a matter of optimizing (computational resources) efficiency in learning?  )

2. According to their documentation on a "Stateful" LSTM:

> **stateful**: Boolean (default False). If True, the last state for each
> sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the
> sample of index i in the following batch.

does that mean that a "Stateful" LSTM for a continuous time series should have a batch_size=1?

As there's not necessarily a predefined relation between sequences of samples, just between samples. The LSTM should then relate it to earlier samples through cell states, instead of predefining this based on the above definition, which seems to assume each batch's sequence of samples follows a learnable trend, as the cell state is reused in the same order for each.

In short: is my interpretation correct and should "Stateful" only be used on a batch size > 1 if the batches represent recurring sequences to learn and otherwise only use it on batch_size=1?

3. Is training a “Stateless” LSTM with a batch_size >= num of samples, i.e. processing the whole dataset in one batch, the same as training a "Stateful" LSTM with a batch_size = 1? As in both cases the cell state wil be maintained and updated according to the previous value when propagating each sample forward into the LSTM right?

Any insights on these questions would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should be aware that standard LSTMs as taught in books and courses, are not stateful.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Would you mind to elaborate on that? Because in theory (from my understanding) they retain their state in the memory/cell state, which makes earlier learnings reusable for future learnings.

Comment: Sure but the state is only kept for the length of the sequence, not between samples in a batch.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy By sequence you mean the timesteps inputs of 1 sample? Because that'd mean there's no use in the cell state for LSTM's that work on single step inputs, which is a very common use, right? It doesn't make much sense to me tbh, also doesn't follow from its definition/equations.

Comment: LSTMs are meant to be used in sequences, it makes no sense to use them if your sequence has length equals to one, and no, it is not a common use.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Hmm confusing, it seems like we're talking about different things, I'm talking about 1 input sample: that doesn't have to represent a sequence itself right? E.g. when predicting the next value in a continuous timeseries, it makes sense that each sample would represent 1 timestep of data, as it grows 1 timestep at a time.

Comment: No, that is incorrect, a single sample is a sequence, with timesteps into the past.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Weird, in every LSTM explanation I've had the input for a LSTM at timestep t, xt, represented 1 timestep of input data in a vector. Which would then be used in combination with the previous hidden state to determine the output. Seems no reason for a need of multiple timesteps as input. I'll digg some deeper into the theory again though because there's a lot of contradiction online regarding the corresponding implementations. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes what you say is correct, but the one timestep input is to the cell, and the input to the whole LSTM layer is a sequence of timesteps, so there is a difference at cell and layer level. The issue with stateful or stateless, is about how  the state is passed between timesteps for the whole sequence, and this happens at the layer level.

Comment: And I totally agree that LSTM is often misunderstood in online information.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Ah I think that's where most of my confusion is originating: the difference between a LSTM Cell and Layer, which I wasn't aware of. Still not really clear to me why it can't just work based on 1 LSTMCell per layer, i.e. as with the equations based on 1 timestep inputs, but I have a better idea where to continue my research so thanks again.